# How to show $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n) = [0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

To show that they are equal, I need to show

$\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n) \subset [0,1]$ and $[0,1] \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)$

My attempt is: let $x \in [0,1] \Rightarrow 0 \leq x \leq 1$, since $1 < 1+1/n, \ \forall n \geq1 \Rightarrow x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n) \Rightarrow [0,1] \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)$

However, I don't know how to show $\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n) \subset [0,1]$. It seems obvious since $\lim_{n \to \infty}  1+1/n = 1$, but I am having trouble to proving that. Any help or hint would be appreciated

Comment: Think of it like this. Suppose $x$ is in the intersection. Is it possible that $x\gt1$? Is it possible that $x\lt0$? No to both (think about it) -> $x\in[0,1]$.

Comment: If $x\in\bigcap_n[0,1+1/n)$ then for any $n$ $0\leq x<1+1/n$. Letting $n\rightarrow\infty$ yields $0\leq x\leq 1$. Alternatively, if $x>1$, choose $n$ large enough so that $\frac{1}{n}<x-1$.

Comment: Pursuing @FShrike's point, the archimedean property of the real numbers is useful.

Comment: [Hint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property): since $x\le 1+1/n$ for each $n$, $x\le\min_n(1+1/n)$. Can you show that minimum is $1$?

Answer (score 2):

Observe that if $x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)$  then you have that
$$x \in [0,1+1/n), \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}\hspace{3mm} (1)$$
That implies that $x \geq 0$ and it remains to prove that $x \leq 1$.

Here you have two options:

- If you have studied about sequence limits, defining $x_n=1+1/n$ we get from (1)  that
  $$x \leq x_n, \forall  n \in \mathbb{N}$$
  So, by the monotonicity of the limit and knowing that $x_n \to 1$ we get that $x \leq 1$ as wanted.
- The second option is to prove it from scratch. Suppose by way of contradiction that $x >1$, then $x-1>0$ and there exists an $n_0 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x-1 > \frac{1}{n_0}$ $\left(\text{just take }  n_0 > \frac{1}{x-1} \right)$. Now, this implies that $x>1+1/n_0$ so $x \not \in [0,1+1/n_0)$ in contradiction with (1).

Answer (score 1):

To simplify this, let $p$ be the statement $x\in [0,1]$ and $q$ be the statement $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n})$

$x\in [0,1]\subset x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n}) \text{ is the same as } p\to q$

and $x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n})\subset x\in [0,1] \text{ is the same as } q\to p \text{ which is equivalent to } \lnot p \to \lnot q$.

As such, since you have proven that $x\in [0,1]\subset x\in \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n})$ ($p\to q$, though may need to be more rigorous especially if for a class). For the next part it may help to assume that $x\notin [0,1]$ and try to conclude that $x\notin \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+\frac{1}{n})$.

Answer (score 0):

Showing
$$[0,1] \subset \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)$$
is equivalent to showing
$$ \overline{[0,1]} \supset \overline{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)}. \tag1$$
Since
$$ \overline{[0,1]}=(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty)$$
and
$$\overline{\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,1+1/n)}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}(-\infty,0)\cup[1+1/n,\infty)=(-\infty,0)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+1/n,\infty), $$
(1) becomes
$$ (-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) \supset (-\infty,0)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+1/n,\infty). \tag2$$
Now we show
$$ \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+1/n,\infty)\subset(1,\infty). \tag3 $$
In fact, for $\forall x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+1/n,\infty)$, then $\exists n$ such that $x\in[1+1/n,\infty)$ and so $x\in(1,\infty)$; namely, (3) is true. Thus
$$ (-\infty,0)\cup\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}[1+1/n,\infty)\subset(-\infty, 0) \cup (1, \infty) $$
or (2) is true.

Comment: While this is true, it also only refers to the easier inclusion that OP doesn't seem to have any problems showing.  Perhaps more critically, the "easy to show" comment for the last line is strange... the easy direct proof of the inclusion in the last line is directly analogous to the easy direct proof of the inclusion in the first line, which makes me wonder what all the intermediate steps were meant to illustrate.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score -1):

If $x$ is in the intersection, that means that $0\leq x<1+\frac{1}{n}$ for all $n\geq1$, using the fact that if $w_n<u_n<v_n$ for all $n$, then $\lim_n w_n\leq \lim_n u_n \leq \lim_n v_n$,  and since $\lim_n 0=0$ and $\lim_n x=x$ (constante sequences) then $0\leq x\leq 1$.